# Rails and codekit - how to disable rails coffescript compilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm using rails 3.2, but I'm compiling my coffee files with CodeKit.

I still want my coffee files to live inside 'assets', but each time I restart rails, it finds them in there and tries to compile them itself.

My files live in /assets/cafe/myscript.coffee, and codekit compiles them into /assets/javascripts/myscript.js

The coffee-rails gem is already commented out in my gemfile (when rails tries to (re) compile it it gives "throw Error("LoadError: no such file to load -- coffee_script)" - though I really dont want it to even try compiling.

Setting "config.assets.compile = false" in application.rb results in "application.js isn't precompiled"

Comment: can you see where that LoadError is thrown from? It looks like it is still trying to run the coffee-rails gem. can you verify that it is not in you Gemfile.lock - some other gems, like RailsAdmin, depend on it and will cause it to be installed and used.

Comment: Even though it's not loaded, it's still finding coffeescripts in /assets and so trying to compile them.  There doesn't seem to be any way to turn this off, which I find surprising.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably just configure your sprockets manifest to not require the whole tree.

edit app/assets/javascripts/application.js

typically it looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

change that to

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require myscript
```

Comment: The coffeescripts are actually in ../coffee though, so it shouldn't be this manifest that's causing them to be compiled?

Answer (score 0):

An (inferior) workaround is to put my coffeescripts inside "App" rather than "assets" (so one more branch up the tree.)

This sucks because it's not where they should go, but at least it does put it outside rails' stalker-tendencies to find coffeescript files anywhere in assets and try to compile them.

Comment: creating folders under /app makes good sense for many things. I guess we just have to live with the /app/assets folder being the domain of the asset pipeline.